# UIScrollView scroller color?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which I am applying a black background, which blends in the scrollbar. I have been looking for a way to change the scrollbars color to white, but I cannot figure it out. Is there a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use "indicatorStyle" property:

```
[scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
```

Comment: I can _never_ remember this property name. Everything else is called scrollIndicatorSomething except this one. Even autocomplete cannot save me from such a badly-named property.

Comment: You can set the color of scrollView indicator, for all UIScrollViews in project, with this:
 [[UIScrollView appearance] setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite];

Comment: UIScrollView.appearance().indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.White

Answer (score 2):

> Both UIScrollView indicator are sub view of UIScrollView. So, we can
>   access subview of UIScrollView and change the property of subview.

**1 .Add UIScrollViewDelegate**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

**2. Add scrollViewDidScroll in implementation section**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
    //get refrence of vertical indicator
    UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
    //set color to vertical indicator
    [verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    //get refrence of horizontal indicator
    UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
    //set color to horizontal indicator
    [horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

> Note:- Because these indicator update every time when you scroll
>   (means reset to default). SO, we put this code in scrollViewDidScroll
>   delegate method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//ScrollView Deleagate
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
        verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


        let horizontalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 2)] as! UIImageView)
        horizontalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
```

Comment: Note that this may crash if the subview you're referencing is not of the type UIImageView!